# Is it possible to scroll beyond the end of a file in the less pager?

Tags: less, scrolling, pager

Is it possible to scroll past the bottom in less?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to see the last line of the file I am viewing at the top of my terminal window (the rest of the screen may be filled with tildes (`~`), which mean *empty line/nothing to see here* in less).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, using <kbd>J</kbd> (as in <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>). So you can go to the end of the file with <kbd>G</kbd>, then scroll down past the end with <kbd>J</kbd> until the last line of the file is at the top of the screen (`less` won’t let you scroll any further).

<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> do the same at the top of the file, scrolling up past the beginning until the first line is at the bottom of the screen.

As [David Ongaro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/46085/david-ongaro) points out, you can use repeat specifiers to avoid having to press <kbd>J</kbd> multiple times: <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> will thus scoll down until the last line is at the top of the screen (unless your terminal has a very large number of rows).

Comment: Yes! They used the word _beyond_ instead of _bottom_: that's why I could not find it. Also, I thought that there should be a flag for it. Nevertheless, this is the correct answer. Thanks! I'll accept it ~soon. :)

Comment: Seems with `100J` one can avoid hitting `J` repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` option also creates "scroll past EOF" behavior in some circumstances.

Without `-c`, when you are near the end of file (the remaining part after the part you currently see is less than a screen height), the <kbd>space</kbd> scrolls down just enough to put the last line of the file on the last line of the screen. <kbd>space</kbd> can be equivalent to <kbd>j</kbd> if there's only one more line to show.

With `-c`, as long as you aren't at EOF already, <kbd>space</kbd> always scrolls forward a full screen height. The top line on the screen after <kbd>space</kbd> will be the line after the one that was at the bottom before the <kbd>space</kbd>. This can leave some portion of the screen unused, and it is filled with the `~` markers.

In `-c` mode, to make the last line the only visible line, <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> is all you need.

...unless the last line in the file is wider than the screen width, in which case you need to repeat the <kbd>K</kbd>.